# How to get the name of all exported functions that are available while doing javascript import?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I just wanted to know is there is a way to know what all action types I can call when I import a third party javascript.

For example:

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore, compose, combineReducers} from 'redux';
```

Without proper documentation, I may not know all the Action Types that I may able to call like these **applyMiddleware**, **createStore**, **compose**, **combineReducers**

Comment: Your code editor should be able to take care of that.

Comment: I am using Atom editor and it suggest only if I know atleast first three character of the particular actiontype.

Comment: Hmm, no experience with Atom, but doesn't it show the exports when you hover on `redux` while holding `ctrl/command` button? Also you might need to get a plugin for that.

Comment: Nope! It shows nothing at all. Any free Editor which does this?

Comment: Try VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/

Comment: Thank you. But VS Code is also not providing the List of action types available.

Comment: Without proper documentation, your only choice is to look at the source or use a debugger. (Or a combination of the two). Notice that I consider intellisense hints as documentation, too.

Answer (score 2):

For the particular case of `redux`, but also for many other packages, you can look to see if the package has a type definition file, typically named `index.d.ts`.

Here are the type definitions for `redux`: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/index.d.ts

If you're working in TypeScript, not just vanilla JavaScript, code editors like Visual Studio Code will definitely recognize type definition files like this for for you, and give you auto-complete and other support. Since I don't work directly in JavaScript very often these days, I can't say how well Visual Studio Code performs in this regard for plain JavaScript.

Even if your development environment isn't given you automated help, you can at least see all that's made available by an imported package by simply looking over the type definition file yourself.